# Set fragment as layout on activity start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new homePage())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error which I got:

> Cannot resolve method add(int, etc...) on line add(R.id.container, new
>   homePage())

So basically i created three fragments and one activity. My activity does not have a lay-out (though it does obviously have a layout page, it's ID is container). I want to add the homePage layout file to the container when the activity starts, but this doesn't seem to be working. I've only created the layout etc so far, and now I'm trying to add the java code but I'm unsure why this isn't working.

I haven't edited the java code of any of the fragments yet so it's basically the code android studio adds to it on creation.

```
public class homePage extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private View view;

    public homePage() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
        Button btnLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginView();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public static homePage newInstance() {
        homePage fragment = new homePage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        return fragment;
    }

    public void loginView(){}

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding this in `onCreate`: `if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(android.R.id.content,
new MyFragment()).commit();
}`

Comment: Could be an issue with the type of Fragment you extended; support or non-stupport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because your `homeFragment` extends the `Fragment` from the support library (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) and hence your `MainActivity` should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` which is a part of `android.app.Fragment`.